# Monitor Network IO (KB/s) on a per-process basis

Tags: c#, java, windows, networking, tcp

Is there any free handy tool with a live monitoring graph to show the Network I/O for a specific process on windows ? (the same way [Resource Monitor](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/closer-windows-resource-monitor/) does it)

*Why not just stick to Resource Monitor ?*
Because I spent too many years on my life coding in front of a computer screen and I ended up being visually deficient. RM graphs are barely exploitable and there is no resize/nor fullscreen mode option.

Process Monitor seemed promising however Disk & Network I/O are merged in the graph.

[image]

Comment: Maybe wireshark would help? I know its a wellknown and well used packet sniffing tool but it might have features you need
http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: yes I tried wireshark it had a pretty fat memory footprint. I tried usng its graphs window but it is not straightforward at all I really got confused. If somebody has a step-by-step solution I welcome it though.

Comment: Well if you are writing the back end network code then you can simply put a counter on you byte send/receive, probably even be able to wrap it into a nice class which is easy to implement. That is if you are ok with just straight numbers being fed.